# How to define categories as varibles with color values in Wordpress ( WP )?

Tags: php, wordpress

I try with this in Single.php and archive.php files:

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php $categories = get_the_category();
$cat = $categories[0]->cat_name;
if ($cat == 'Meriendas') { ?>
    .page-title.solid-bg {background-color: #64a445!important;}
<?php }
elseif ($cat == 'Consejos') { ?>
    .page-title.solid-bg {background-color: #e62750!important;}
<?php }
else { ?>
    .page-title.solid-bg {background-color: #394299!important;}
<?php } ?>
</style>
```

It work, but this can be better. Only work if the post have a unique one category assigned.

Any ideas? ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would probably do is add the category to the body class using the [`body_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class) filter:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ){
    if( is_single() ){
        if( $categories = get_the_category() ){
            foreach( $categories as $term ){
                $class = sanitize_html_class( $term->slug, $term->term_id );

                $classes[] = "category-$class";
            }
        }
    }

    return $classes;
});
```

What this will do is add classes to the body on single posts, such as: `category-consejos`. Note that if you have multiple categories, it will add multiple categories, so if you want one style to override another, you'll need to put it lower in your CSS.

The above function will allow you to drop the following styles to your `style.css` file, Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS, or even append them with [`wp_add_inline_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style), whatever best suites your needs.

```
.page-title.solid-bg {
    background-color: #394299 !important;
}

.category-meriendas .page-title.solid-bg {
    background-color: #64a445 !important;
}

.category-consejos .page-title.solid-bg {
    background-color: #e62750 !important;
}
```

Note you shouldn't need to add any special conditions for the category/archives, because the [`body_class()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) function already accounts for category archives.